# How to copy database file from document directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, zip

I make an application that contain *SqliteDatabase* I copy database feel from document directory like as :

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if(!success) {

   NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
   success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

   if (!success)
      NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath
{   
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
 }
```

Then it is working fine but now i want to make a `.zip` file of my database and fetch from it like as I make `database.zip` file and in my `.zip` file it contain `database.sqlite` file then how to fetch data from it.

I want to make .zip file because my database size is to large and I use `VACUUM` but my database size is refuse only few MB but I want more less size.

Comment: Formatted post and added tags